# How to solve TypeError: unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary, hashable

I have two lists I would like to modify a particular content of the first list and send the output but when I try to modify it, am getting an error 
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. 
I am using python with mongodb.

The two lists are

```
data = [{"id" : ["5630baac3f32df134c18b682","564b22373f32df05fc905564"],"phone" : ["9988776655","9638527410"], "Request": "Support staff", "Date": "19-11-2015"}]
test = [{"phone" : "9638527410", "id": "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}]
id = {}
for info in chain(data, test):
    id.setdefault(info['id'], {}).update(info)
res = list(id.values())
print(res)
```

The required output is

```
[{"phone" : "9638527410", "id": "5630baac3f32df134c18b682", "Request": "Support staff", "Date": "19-11-2015"}]
```

What is the mistake I am making here?

Can anyone guide me how I can get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You are using list as an key in the dictionary. List is not a hashable type in python. So, it can not be used as key in the dictionary. Only hashable types such as tuple, strings, numbers can be used as key in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, Is there any other by which I can get the desired result

Comment: Do you want to pick values for id and phone from "id" : ["5630baac3f32df134c18b682","564b22373f32df05fc905564"],"phone" : ["9988776655","9638527410"] randomly ?

Comment: no only the values from the second list. i want only the values from `test` list to be in the output list