# Unhashiable Type: 'List'

Tags: python

Basically I had first made a dictionary into a list then got out 6 keys in that list. I also got the user to enter some values. Now i want to put the keys and values back into another dictionary.

I have tried just putting it in normal dictionary format for example:

```
eliminate1 = {newcouple1:Couple01,newcouple2:Couple02,newcouple3:Couple03,newcouple4:Couple04}

import operator
from operator import itemgetter
eliminate1 = {newcouple1:Couple01,newcouple2:Couple02,newcouple3:Couple03,newcouple4:Couple04}
sorted_eliminate1 = sorted(eliminate1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
gone = print("These Couples have been eliminated: ",dict(sorted_eliminate[0:2]))
gone1 = dict(sorted_eliminate1[0:2])
remaining01 = print("These are the remaining couples: ",dict(sorted(eliminate1.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[2:]))
remaining1 = dict(sorted(eliminate1.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[2:])
```

I got an error running the code:

```
eliminate1 = {newcouple1:Couple01,newcouple2:Couple02,newcouple3:Couple03,newcouple4:Couple04}
```

This is the error:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: mutable objects cannot be used ad dictionary keys

Comment: `lists`s cannot be used as dictionary keys since they are mutable. Seems `newcouple1` or some other `newCouple` is a list. try turning them into `tuple`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve TypeError: unhashable type 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772115/how-to-solve-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: Can you please show me some code to how i can change the list to a tuple.

Comment: Please provide some samples of how `eliminate1` looks like

Comment: Googling "how i can change the list to a tuple" gives you *a lot* of examples.

Answer (score 0):

`Lists` are unhashable because they are mutable. Could you imagine if a `dictionary` `key` was assigned to a `value`, and then that `key` was changed? It'd be a nightmare.

Convert the `lists` into `tuples` to make them hashable

Comment: Can you please show some code to how i can turn this into a tuple.

Comment: Some or all of your `newCouple`'s are lists. Wrap them with `tuple()`

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Why are dictionaries so fast?

Because, when you look something up, python does not look for the object. Instead, it assigns an integer to each object (the *hash value*), and searches for that integer instead.

However, that happens only when you insert it in the dictionary. If the value of the object changed later, the hash value would not, and the dictionary would not be able to find the object.

So, you can't put mutable objects in a dict. For a list, the easiest solution is to convert it into a tuple, eg instead of

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]
x = { lst: "hello" }
```

write

```py
lst  = [1, 2, 3]
x = { tuple(lst): "hello" }
```